# SCCM connect via HttpClient to Odata or WMI REST on Linux

Tags: c#, .net-core, sccm

I am currently connecting to Microsoft Endpoint Configuration Manager (MECM) using HttpClient which use a HttpClientHandler to set credentials via Negotiate.

This works fine on Windows machines but when it comes to run on Linux i dont have a trust between the container and the Windows server.

I am trying to understand if there is a better way to authenticate such as generating a bearer token.

```
var credentialsCache = new CredentialCache();
        credentialsCache.Add(new Uri(rootBaseUrl), WindowAuthenticationMechanisms.Negotiate,
           new NetworkCredential(username, password));

       
var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    Credentials = credentialsCache,
    PreAuthenticate = true
};

var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(handler)
{
   Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10),
   BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl)
};
```

MECM server base endpoints I am using are:

```
https://<SCCMServerFQDN>/AdminService/wmi/
https://<SCCMServerFQDN>/AdminService/v1.0/
```

Any advice how I can use similar code on linux, without having to setup a trust as it will be a bit of nightmare when doing within a container.

Thanks in advance